# Could not find space (120 bytes) for variable

Tags: c++, c, arrays, int, pic

I have an array defined with 60 hex values.

```
int ary[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13,
    0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 
    0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 
    0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59 
};
```

When i compile this i get the error

```
could not find space (120 bytes) for variable _ary
```

Why is this happening, This is for a PIC program and i need the array to be type of `int`. What can i do?

Comment: You need to keep it as a byte why store it as a int you might as well just cast it into a int later when you need too.

Comment: Also, the sequence of numbers looks pretty predictable. Can't they be generated on-the-fly?

Comment: If you're targeting a part that has, say, 80 byte banks, you can't create a 120 byte contiguous array.

Comment: "Why is this happening" is because your PIC is running out of space to store constant data.  Also, confident you do not _need_ to store array as `int`.  Use `signed char` instead.

Comment: You might try declaring it `const` (const int ary[]) unless you need to change the values at runtime. , some pic compilers might place that in another kind of memory (which may or may not have the space required).

Comment: This doesn't look like you're doing C++. What is your target environment? What compiler are you using? I'm rather certain gcc and visual studio will never give you that error.

Comment: @nos, It worked. making the array const worked. :) thanks a lot for your help.